# Iam getting android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 24: Error inflating class

Tags: android

MY Activity_Donar XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.karthi.bloodbankk.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_donar"
android:background="@drawable/bloodbank3">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="BRING A LIFE BACK TO POWER"
    android:id="@+id/etquote"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#070707" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etDonarName"
    android:hint="DonorName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etquote"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etBg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etDonarName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Blood Group" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPhone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etBg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Phone No" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etLocation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPhone"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Location" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etCity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="City" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:id="@+id/bSubmi"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etCity"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SEARCH FOR DONORS"
    android:id="@+id/bSearch"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bSubmi"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

I am getting `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 24: Error inflating class`. What should I do?
All my id's for edit texts and buttons in android classes are same as in xml files. But I am unable to get it..

I am getting a
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

> Process: com.example.karthi.bloodbankk, PID: 1953
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.karthi.bloodbankk/com.example.karthi.bloodbankk.DonarActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>                                                                                    at com.example.karthi.bloodbankk.DonarActivity.onCreate(DonarActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>                                                                                    at com.example.karthi.bloodbankk.DonarActivity.onCreate(DonarActivity.java:39) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>                                                                                    at com.example.karthi.bloodbankk.DonarActivity.onCreate(DonarActivity.java:39) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20971532 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 11MB until OOM
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
>                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.(View.java:3948)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:573)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:248)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:244)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:240)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>                                                                                    at com.example.karthi.bloodbankk.DonarActivity.onCreate(DonarActivity.java:39) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Please post the **entire** stack trace. There should be one or more pieces to this, where each piece starts with a "Caused by" line and has more lines like you have in your question.

Comment: Does your layout have <include> tag ?

Comment: `20971532 byte` that's a big image

Comment: Do I remove Image?

Comment: Thanks njzk2., its working

Comment: i think you background image "bloodbank3" is too large.... use small size image in project.and replace this...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the xml file, seems closing tag of RelativeLayout is not added.

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add the above tag at the end of the file and check.